# Styling and CSS

Tags: css

Recently i found an issue with the styling of a text-area. When i inserted the following code in the view file of a **Yii** Application and below given styling code in the **CSS** file, the border of the text area remained as it is when encountered an error, i.e. when i didn't enter any text into a the text-area.

**View file code**

```
<div class="form">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'body'); ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'body',array('style' => 'min-width:80%;max-width:80%;min- height:20%;max-height:200px;border:1px solid #666')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'body'); ?>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form .error label:first-child,.form .error {
color:#C00;
}
.form div.error textarea,div.form textarea.error{
background:#FEE;
border-color:#C00;
}
```

Now when i insert the inline **CSS** code inside the external stylesheet:

```
 array('style' => 'min-width:80%;max-width:80%;min- height:20%;max-height:200px')
```

The color of the border of the text-area changes as I wanted. I just wanted to know, whether this happens due to the higher priority of the inline style than that of the stylesheet or due to any other reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a specificity issue, you can read about it [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) but the general gist is a sort of priority in CSS like so:

1. `!important`
2. Inline styles `div style="color=red"`
3. Element ID's `div id=""`
4. Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes `class="", :focus`
5. Elements and pseudo-elements `body, :before`

The first thing you can do to test if it IS a specificity issue is to use `!important` after the declaration, if that works, it is, you are defining the style elsewhere and need to overwrite it with something more specific (probably requires an ID)

Comment: That means if i use an inline style, like I previously used.. it will require the '!imporant' attribute in order to change the border on an error ?

Comment: @SumitGera Yes, the only way to over ride inline is to use `!important`, both of which are generally bad practice so if you can avoid inline styles that is best

Comment: So I can assume that the current styling is the best for my application.